# How plot many points 3d in matplotlib

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I am trying to plot 8000 points in three dimensions (x,y,z) of a terrain with matplotlib using the function `contourf` when I run the code I get the error

> 'OverflowError: In draw_path_collection: Exceeded cell block limit'

I tried to solve this with `"mpl.rcParams['agg.path.chunksize'] = 20000"` 
but this did not resolve the issue. Here is my code

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm
from scipy.interpolate import griddata
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib as mpl
datos = pd.read_csv('zrh_terrain.txt', header =0)
dats=500
mpl.rcParams['agg.path.chunksize'] = 20000
X=datos.iloc[0:dats,0].values
Y=datos.iloc[0:dats,1].values
Z=datos.iloc[0:dats,2].values
dt_bar=np.linspace(Z.min(),Z.max(),10)
xi,yi= np.meshgrid(X,Y)
zi = griddata((X,Y),Z,(xi,yi),method='nearest')
plt.contourf(xi,yi,zi,extend='both',vmin=dt_bar[0],vmax=dt_bar[-1],
                cmap=cm.terrain)
```

Comment: You can refer to this! https://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/tutorial.html

Comment: You have a lot of duplicate (or closeby) points in your data due to meshgridding the original data. Better interpolate on a grid, which does not contain duplicates and with a constant distance between points. Check [this example](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/images_contours_and_fields/irregulardatagrid.html).